# addSnapshotListener to fetch only changes in firebase collection

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, listener

I've added `addSnapshotListener` like:

```
            doc?.reference.collection("thread")
                .order(by: "created", descending: true)
                .addSnapshotListener(includeMetadataChanges: true, listener: { (threadQuery, error) in

            if let error = error {
                print("Error: \(error)")
                return
            } else {
                //print(threadQuery?.documents.count)
                    for message in threadQuery!.documents {
                        self.removeAllOverlays()
                        print("Data: \(message.data())")
                    }
            }
            })
```

Everytime a new document is added to `thread` it loads the full thread. How can I only fetch the new document added in the `thread` collection?

Answer (score 2):

To keep this simple, assume theres a users collection like this

```
users
   doc_0
      name: "Pete"
   doc_1
      name: "Lewis"
   doc_2
      name: "Clark"
```

the following code will attach an observer to the users node and notify us when a user is added, modified or removed. Noting that upon first run, it will iterate over each user, one at a time and fire .added, which would allow you to initially populate an array for example.

```
func observeUserChanges() {
    let usersCollectionRef = self.db.collection("users")
    usersCollectionRef.addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
        guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
            print("Error fetching snapshots: \(error!)")
            return
        }

        snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { diff in
            let userName = diff.document.get("name") as? String ?? "No Name"
            if (diff.type == .added) {
                print("Added user: \(userName)")
            }
            if (diff.type == .modified) {
                print("Modified user: \(userName)")
            }
            if (diff.type == .removed) {
                print("Removed user: \(userName)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When first run it output this

```
Added user: Pete
Added user: Lewis
Added user: Clark
```

then when a new user is added, we see this

```
Added user: Ted
```

when Ted is removed

```
Removed user: Ted
```